# WordPress Single Sign-on and Persistent Sessions Across Different Domains

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite, auth0

I'm trying to implement a single set of credentials across multiple WordPress installs that sit on the *same server* but on *different domains* entirely. e.g. squirrel.com, badger.es, horse.coffee.

I have been looking at [auth0](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/auth0/) for sharing credentials, but I still need to login using those same shared, valid, credentials on each individual site, where ideally I could visit one of the other sites and be already authenticated.

Is this possible using auth0 or some similar method? Should I be looking at multisite instead?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you